# A smooth nonzero function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with uniformly bounded derivatives tending to zero at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

$\def\scrBp{\mathscr B\boldsymbol.}\def\rD{{\rm D}\kern.4mm}\def\ssp{\kern.4mm}\def\bbR{\mathbb R}
$For a certain purpose I invented the Banach space $\scrBp^\infty(\ssp\bbR\ssp)$ defined as follows. The vectors are all smooth functions $x:\bbR\to\bbR$ such that there is $M\in\bbR^+$ with $|\,\rD^kx(t)\,|\le M$ and $\lim_{\,s\to\pm\infty\,}|\,\rD^kx(s)\,|=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb N_0$ and $t\in\bbR$ . The norm of $x$ is the infimum of the set of all these $M$ . Now I am wondering whether this space has any nonzero vectors. Hence the question.

Comment: I doubt so, since neither $e^{-x^2}$-like functions nor functions from $C_c^\infty$ will be in there (the uniform constant breaks these) as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can a continuous and differentiable function approach some finite limit as $x\to\infty$, without its derivative approaching $0$?

Comment: @Nishant An example is $t\mapsto t^{-1}\,\sin(t^2)$ .

Comment: A smooth function with uniformly bounded derivatives is real-analytic, and its Taylor series converges on all of $\mathbb{C}$, so it would be the restriction of an entire function to the real axis. I'm almost sure that means your space is $\{0\}$, but I don't see a proof yet.

Comment: In view of Daniel Fischer's comment above, I added the "complex-analysis" tag.

Comment: Contrary to @DanielFischer 's conjecture, one can use Fourier methods to show that there are a lot of these functions (see my answer). It would be interesting to me what the original context of the invention of that Banach space was (had it something to do with Fourier analysis?)? Actually, Daniel's comment gave me the idea for the proof below, because I recalled that every function with compact support has an analytic Fourier transform, which gave me the idea to use Fourier methods.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks for the positive answer. The original context for which I invented the space was that I wanted to construct a contravariant *smooth* functor in the sense of Serge Lang's §III.4 in his book *Differential Manifolds*. I wanted the functor be such that via Lang's construction one can associate an infinite-rank Banach vector bundle with the tangent bundle of a finite-dimensional smooth manifold. It is easy to construct such *covariant* functors as well as contravariant functors in the category of Fréchet spaces which lead to vector bundles with non-Banach Fréchet fibres. (cont.)

Comment: Actually, for my purpose, I need the space over all finite-dimensional vector spaces, but the generalization from the one-dimensional case is straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there are a lot of these functions. To see this,
one possibility is to use the theory of the Fourier transform:

Choose some $\varphi\in C_{c}^{\infty}\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi},\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)\right)$
and let $f:=\mathcal{F}\varphi=\widehat{\varphi}$ be the Fourier
transform of $\varphi$, i.e.
$$
f\left(\xi\right)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi\left(x\right)\cdot e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,{\rm d}x.
$$
By the usual properties of the Fourier transform, we conclude that
$f\in\mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ is a Schwartz-function,
which means 
$$
C_{m,n}:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left|x^{m}\cdot\partial^{n}f\left(x\right)\right|<\infty
$$
 for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$. In particular, this implies (for
$\left|x\right|\geq1$):
$$
\left|\partial^{n}f\left(x\right)\right|=\left|\frac{x\cdot\partial^{n}f\left(x\right)}{x}\right|\leq\frac{C_{1,n}}{\left|x\right|}\xrightarrow[x\to\pm\infty]{}0
$$
so that $f$ fulfills the second one of your requirements.

By choosing (e.g.) $\varphi\geq0$ and $\varphi\not\equiv0$, we can
also ensure that $f\left(0\right)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x>0$,
i.e. $f\not\equiv0$ (alternatively, we have $\varphi=\mathcal{F}^{-1}f$,
so that $f\not\equiv0$ holds as soon as $\varphi\not\equiv0$ is
true).

Finally, we can differentiate "under the integral sign" to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left|\partial^{n}f\left(\xi\right)\right| & = & \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi\left(x\right)\cdot\frac{{\rm d}^{n}}{{\rm d}\xi^{n}}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,{\rm d}x\right|\\
 & = & \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi\left(x\right)\cdot\left(-2\pi ix\right)^{n}\cdot e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,{\rm d}x\right|\\
 & \leq & \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\varphi\left(x\right)\right|\cdot\left|2\pi x\right|^{n}\,{\rm d}x\\
 & \overset{{\rm supp}\left(\varphi\right)\subset\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi},\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)}{\leq} & \int_{-\frac{1}{2\pi}}^{\frac{1}{2\pi}}\left|\varphi\left(x\right)\right|\cdot\left|2\pi x\right|^{n}\,{\rm d}x\\
 & \leq & \int_{-\frac{1}{2\pi}}^{\frac{1}{2\pi}}\left|\varphi\left(x\right)\right|\,{\rm d}x\leq\left\Vert \varphi\right\Vert _{L^{1}},
\end{eqnarray*}
so that the derivatives of $f$ are also uniformly bounded, which is the first of your desired properties.